# Restriction of a Smooth chart is Again a Smooth Chart

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with $\mathscr A=\{(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)\}_{\alpha\in J}$ being its smooth structure.

Let $V$ be open in $M$ and $(U,\varphi)\in \mathscr A$.

Define $\psi:U\cap V\to \varphi(U\cap V)$ as $\psi(p)=\varphi(p)$ for all $p\in V$.

We note that $(V\cap U,\psi)$ is a chart on $M$.

**QUESTION**: Does $(V\cap U,\psi)\in\mathscr A$?

I think the answer to the above question is yes because $(V\cap U,\psi)$ is smoothly compatible with every member of $\mathscr A$. Thus $(V\cap U,\psi)\in\mathscr A$.

Can somebody confirm that I am correct or else point out a mistake?

PS: I am an absolute beginner in Differential Geometry.

Thank you.

Comment: If $\mathscr A$ is a **maximal** atlas, then yes. All restrictions of charts are smoothly compatible with all other charts, so they are already in the maximal atlas.

Comment: Yes. $\mathscr A$ is a maximal atlas. The text I am reading defines a 'smooth structure' as a maximal atlas.